# Nothing shows up inside a tikz matrix

Tags: tikz-pgf

I was experimenting the matrix shape of tikz:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[matrix, rotate=0, yshift=0cm, column sep=0.2cm, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=10cm] (SIMDATA) {
        \draw[rectangle,draw=red,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm] {}; &
        \draw[rectangle,draw=blue,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm]{}; &
        \draw[rectangle,draw=green,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm]{}; &
        \draw[rectangle,draw=yellow,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm]{}; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

I was expecting the above code to produce four verically placed bars aligned in one row, that is the reason why I nest the rectangles inside a tikz matrix. But the code produces nothing, with no error no warning:

[image]

Is there anything wrong with my code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\draw` is for drawing paths, e.g. `\draw (0,0) -- (1,1);`. You seem to want `\node` instead:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node[matrix, rotate=0, yshift=0cm, column sep=0.2cm, minimum width=10cm, minimum height=10cm] (SIMDATA) {
        \node[rectangle,draw=red,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm] {}; &
        \node[rectangle,draw=blue,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm]{}; &
        \node[rectangle,draw=green,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm]{}; &
        \node[rectangle,draw=yellow,fill=gray,minimum width=0.6cm, minimum height=5.8cm]{}; \\
    };
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: So, `\draw` is working only if we provide the two corner coordinates of the rectangle?

Comment: You can also provide other things than rectangles. However it needs a path. `\draw` is just a shortcut for `\path[draw]`

Comment: @TianjianQin Well, using `\draw` to draw a line only works if you specify at least two coordinates. This makes sense, as it is logically unfeasable to draw a line with only one coordinate. There are operators such as `circle` where you specify one coordinate (the center) and a radius, for example. However, the operator `rectangle` requires two coordinates. Maybe have a look at the [online Ti*k*Z manual](https://tikz.dev) which contains nice tutorials.